# x-rates Excel VBA data pulling

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I am pretty new to Excel VBA and I'm having trouble pulling data from this website: https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=CAD&amount=1&date=2018-11-05. I would like to automate this process so I can get these rates every month. This is as far as I have gotten and I get lost from here:

'start a new subroutine called SearchBot

Sub SearchBot()

```
'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=CAD&amount=1"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. It uses [XMLHTTP](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) as a faster retrieval method. Concatenates yesterday's date into the URL to get the latest rates. The alphabetized table is selected by its class name and index position.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, clipboard As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=CAD&amount=1&date=" & Format$(Date - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd"), False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        clipboard.SetText .querySelectorAll(".ratesTable").item(1).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
    End With     
    ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial 
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Adding a `Set ws = Nothing`, `Set clipboard = Nothing`, and `Set html = Nothing` at the end. You need to clean the mess.

Comment: @NELMVN It's my understanding that garbage collection will take care of that anyway, since the object references will go out of scope at the end of the procedure. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: NELMVN As pointed out by @chillin  this will be cleared up when the sub goes out of scope.Object variables will release their reference and the runtime calls the object’s Release method to decrement the object’s reference count. This is the same as set x = Nothing.